# Custom Claim using complex type is not deserialized correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity

I'm using Claims authentication in an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I'm following all the standard patterns and it's working well. However I've just noticed that custom claims that use complex types are not being deserialized correctly.

I have a Custom Claim as follows: (Role was an enum but has changed it to a long to simplify things)

```
[DataContract(Name = "ClientRoleClaim", Namespace = "MyCompany.MyApplication.Security.Claims")]
public sealed class ClientRoleClaim : System.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim
{
    public ClientRoleClaim(Guid clientId, Role role)
        : base(MyAppClaimTypes.ClientRole, String.Empty, Rights.PossessProperty)
    {
        ClientId = clientId;
        Role = (long)role;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "ClientId")]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Role")]
    public long Role { get; set; }
}
```

FYI: MyAppClaimTypes.ClientRole is just a static class with const string properties on it.

In my custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager I create a list of claims and add my complex ClientRoleClaim and create my principal as follows:

```
// Create the claims
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress),
    new ClientIdClaim(user.ClientEntityId),
    new ClientRoleClaim(user.ClientEntityId, 1)
};

claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom");
return new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
```

The token is then persisted as follows:

```
private void EstablishSession(ClaimsPrincipal newPrincipal)
{
    var hours = Configuration.Configuration.GetSetting("SignIntPeriodInHours").ParseAs<int>().GetValueOrDefault(8);
    var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(newPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(hours));
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
}
```

Everything appears to work fine but when I subsequently try to access ClamsPrincipal.Current.Claims all the claims are present, including the custom claim of type MyAppClaimTypes.ClientRole, but it is of type System.Security.Claims.Claim and I have no way of accessing the ClientId and Role properties.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mat

Answer (score 1):

This is not designed to work like this. Claims are tuples, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Create claim with custom claim type and structured resource type  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734687(v=vs.110).aspx